# Matlab simple GUI input to function

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have a function `Func.m` which I want to pass a parameter to it using GUI in Matlab. The GUI will has a text_box and a button, where the text inside the textbox will be passed to function `Func.m` when the button is pressed. So if anyone could please advise as this is my first time to use Matlab GUI

Comment: Please check some tutorials and examples first. This site can help you to answer questions if you get really stuck, but don't ask it here if you did not try it first. If you did try, please show what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the string from the button in your GUI using the following command.

```
buttonString = get(handles.ButtonName,'String')
```

You can then just call your function the same way you would any other function. Just make sure the function, if in a separate file, is in the same directory as your GUI `*.m` file, or just add whatever directory it is in to your path.

```
returnVal = someFunction(buttonString);
```